# Will this graphics card fit my motherboard?

Tags: graphics, pci-express

P31-ES3G motherboard:

Which has expansion slots:

```
1 x PCI Express x16 slot
3 x PCI Express x1 slots
3 x PCI slots
```

Was thinking of upgrading my graphics card to a:

XFX R7850 CORE EDITION PCI EXPRESS 2 GB MEMORY DDR5

I have 750W PSU

As not expert just wanted to confirm this would work on my board?
and if not what do I need to bear in mind when purchasing a new card?

Comment: That is a doublewide card so even though it will fit in the PCIe slot, it will take up to slots.  Although its not a very long card, its still long, make sure it wont bump into things sticking up on the mobo

Comment: The requirements of the card are clearly laid out.  The diminsions of the card are known.  You didn't provide the diminsions of your case, it might fit the motherboard, but it could in theory not even fit in the case.

Answer (score 2):

You said your MOBO has a PCIe x16 slot, which houses any PCIe card.

The card is PCIe, so yes, it will fit.

Answer (score -1):

This Radeon 7850 will have absolutely zero issues fitting onto your motherboard in the `PCI Express x16 slot` and your PSU has more than enough power to run it and even overclock the card and CPU to the max if you wish.

My biggest concern is whether or not your case has enough room for the length of the card. Can you post the make and model of your case? I personally have an Antec Eleven Hundred which has beastly amounts of room and fits my Asus Radeon 7870 with inches to spare.